# Jquery click event isn't firing anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this really large project so i can't show you all the code.I programmed a couple of jquery.click events on some buttons and that worked perfectly. Now for an unknown reason one of the four jquery.click events doesn't fire anymore. It is the third button that doesn't work anymore the one with the most code in the jquery.click event, the one with id = reservatie_verwijderen

This is the jquery programming code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$("#nieuwe_reservatie").click(function(){
    dialog.dialog( "open" );     
});
$("#klant_aanmaken").click(function(){
    dialog_klant.dialog("open"); 
});
$("#reservatie_verwijderen").click(function(){
    alert("Test");
    var zekerheid = confirm("Ben je zeker dat je deze reservatie wilt verwijderen?");
    if (zekerheid == true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "server/verwijder_reservatie.php", 
        });
    }
});
$("#factuur_afdrukken").click(function() {
    window.open("server/Contract.php");
});
});
```

So i put in an alert function to see if the click event works but the alert function doesn't get executed either. The following code is the html code:

```
<button class="actie_knop" id="nieuwe_reservatie">Nieuwe Reservatie</button>
<button class="actie_knop" id="reservatie_verwijderen">Reservatie Verwijderen</button>
<button class="actie_knop" id="factuur_afdrukken">Factuur Afdrukken</button>
<button class="actie_knop" id="klant_aanmaken">Klant Aanmaken</button>
```

And to say it before anyone asks, I deleted all the parts that I added since it didn't work anymore and tested it to see if any of the newly added code was the problem but even then the click event wouldn't fire anymore. So I changed nothing but now after it worked for a week or two it doesn't work anymore.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Issue is with something else which is not been shown in provided code..

Comment: please recreate the problem for us to try and solve it

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=20C3A5897A15D09!40643&authkey=!AOON3RLw0T0ieN8&ithint=file%2cphp

Comment: above is a link with the full document

Comment: it is the third button that doesn't work anymore the one with the most code in the jquery.click event

Comment: the document contains php, so can't recreate whatever html it generates. Btw, I recommend changing passwords !!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no, i don't get errors in the consol

Comment: The fact that no error is displayed in the console suggests something goes wrong in the jQuery constructor for #reservatie_verwijderen. Can you post the results of a `console.log($('#reservatie_verwijderen'));` ? its best to put the command right above the click handler.